# Two bodies orbiting around barycenter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

There are two bodies with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ orbiting around barycenter. Distances to both bodies from barycenter are $r_1$ and $r_2$ . First body has known velocity $v_1$ as on the picture :

[image: two-body-problem]

My goal is to get properties of trajectories for both bodies. I have a solution for the case when body is orbiting around stationary mass.

Question is, is it possible to convert this problem to two separate problems where each body is orbiting around stationary point - barycenter with some mass $M$ ?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689759/

Answer (score 1):

Both bodies orbit on similar ellipses with their size ratio

$$\frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{m_2}{m_1}$$

As the orbital period is the same for both ($r_1$ and $r_2$ are always collinear), we have therefore also

$$\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{m_2}{m_1}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you please explain how to use these equations? My goal is to somehow convert the problem to a problem of body orbiting around stationary mass. I've come across a possibility to convert two-body problem to a problem of body with reduced mass orbiting around barycenter but didn't found straight forward explanation how to do this and how to extract solution to original problem.

Comment: @michal12457 You can refer the orbit of $m_1$ to the location of $m_2$ by using the total mass $m_1+m_2$ instead of $m_2$ and the reduced mass $m_1\cdot m_2/(m_1+m_2)$ instead of $m_1$. The orbital radius vector is then obviously $r_1+r_2$ . See this link for step by step explanation https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestialhtml/node11.html